# clear text fields in all html text boxes when clicking on one html text box

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textbox

I have a form in which I have three text fields, name,latitude and longitude.  These forms are already pre-filled however, I want to when I click on latitude and longitude all the pre-filled text values to be cleared.  How can I do this?

Comment: Please include your code so that we can see what you're working with.

Comment: @Ryan While I generally agree that code should be supplied with the question. This question is pretty clear about what is being dealt with.

Comment: It does indeed matter, as if there are any specified requirements for classes, names, or ids for the form elements, that can dictate the appropriate solution.

Comment: @Ryan All good points, but again, this is a very simplistic question with a simplistic answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply gather references to all the input elements in an array and then iterate the array, clearing out the contents upon each iteration:

```js
// Get a reference to the button
var btn = document.getElementById("clear");

// Set the button up for a click event handler
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  // Get all the input elements that are text fields and convert that list into an array
  // Loop through that array and clear the value of each text field
  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']")).forEach(function(element){
    element.value = "";
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" value="abc">
<input type="text" value="abc">
<input type="text" value="abc">
<input type="text" value="abc">
<input type="text" value="abc">
<button id="clear">Clear all text fields</button>
```

Comment: To what I understand, the question implies that the click event should be applied to the text input(s) (one or multiple), not a separate button.

Comment: @Ryan This solution is easily adaptable to be triggered upon any action. Again, this question is not rocket science.